# B-Spline Curves coefficients - division by zero (code in DELPHI)

Tags: delphi, bspline, cubic-bezier

I was trying to implement the following recursive formula to my code
[image]

but to my surprise it turns out that after implementing this to DELPHI, I get an error due to division by zero. I am 98% sure that my knot vector is correctly calculated, which in a way means there shouldn't be any divisions by zero. I am 70% sure that the recursive formula is correctly implemented, for that reason I am posting my code here:

```
program project1;

uses
SysUtils;

Type
  TRealPoint = record
    x: single;
    y: single;
  end;

type
  TSample = Class(TObject)
    public
      KnotVector: array of single;
      FitPoints: array of TRealPoint;
      Degree: integer;
      constructor Create; overload;
      function Coefficient(i, p: integer; Knot: single): single;
      procedure GetKnots;
      destructor Destroy; overload;
  end;

constructor TSample.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TSample.Coefficient(i, p: integer; Knot: single): single;
var
  s1, s2: single;
begin
   If (p = 0) then
   begin
     If (KnotVector[i] <= Knot) And (Knot < KnotVector[i+1]) then Result := 1.0
     else Result := 0.0;
   end
   else
   begin
     s1 := (Knot - KnotVector[i])*Coefficient(i, p-1, Knot)/(KnotVector[i+p] - KnotVector[i]); //THIS LINE ERRORS due to division by zero ???
     s2 := (KnotVector[i+p+1]-Knot)*Coefficient(i+1,p-1,Knot)/(KnotVector[i+p+1]-KnotVector[i+1]);
     Result := s1 + s2;
   end;
end;

procedure TSample.GetKnots();
var
  KnotValue: single;
  i, MaxKnot: integer;
begin
  // KNOTS
  KnotValue:= 0.0;
  SetLength(KnotVector, Length(FitPoints) + 1 + Degree);
  MaxKnot:= Length(KnotVector) - (2*Degree + 1);
  for i := Low(KnotVector) to High(KnotVector) do
  begin
    if i <= (Degree) then KnotVector[i] := KnotValue / MaxKnot
    else if i > Length(FitPoints) then KnotVector[i] := KnotValue / MaxKnot
    else
    begin
      KnotValue := KnotValue + 1.0;
      KnotVector[i] := KnotValue / MaxKnot;
    end;
  end;
end;

destructor TSample.Destroy;
begin
   inherited;
end;

var
  i, j: integer;
  Test: TSample;
  N: array of array of single;
begin
  Test := TSample.Create;
  //define degree
  Test.Degree := 3;
  //random fit points
  j := 15;
  SetLength(Test.FitPoints, j + 1 + Test.Degree);
  For i := Low(Test.FitPoints) to High(Test.FitPoints) do
  begin
    Test.FitPoints[i].x := Random()*2000;
    Test.FitPoints[i].y := Random()*2000;
  end;
  //get knot vector
  Test.GetKnots;
  //get coefficients
  SetLength(N, j+1, j+1);
  For j := Low(N) to High(N) do
  begin
    For i := Low(N[j]) to High(N[j]) do
      begin
        N[j, i] := Test.Coefficient(i,3,Test.KnotVector[j]);
        write(floattostrf(N[j,i], ffFixed, 2, 2) + ', ');
      end;
    writeln();
  end;
  readln();
  Test.Free;
end.
```

Basically I'm not sure how to continue. I would need the values of matrix N ([see this link](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html)) of basis coefficients but somehow using the formula from [this link](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-coef.html) leads me to division by zero.

So... Is there a totally different way how to calculate those coefficients or what is the problem here?

**UPDATE**

Instead of using my own idea i tried to implement the algorithm from [here](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-coef.html) as suggested by [Dsm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4796610/dsm) in the comments. As a result, there is no more divison by zero, but the result is totally unexpected anyways.

For n + 1 = 10 random fit points with spline degree 3 the basis matrix N (see [link](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html)) is singular - as seen from the attached image.

[image]

Instead of that I would expect the matrix to be [band matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix). Anyway, here is my updated code:

```
program project1;

uses
SysUtils;

Type
  TRealPoint = record
    x: single;
    y: single;
  end;

type
  TMatrix = array of array of double;

type
  TSample = Class(TObject)
    public
      KnotVector: array of double;
      FitPoints: array of TRealPoint;
      SplineDegree: integer;
      Temp: array of double;
      A: TMatrix;
      procedure GetKnots;
      function GetBasis(Parameter: double): boolean;
      procedure FormBasisMatrix;
  end;

procedure TSample.GetKnots();
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  // KNOTS
  //https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-knot-generation.html
  SetLength(KnotVector, Length(FitPoints) + SplineDegree + 1);
  for i := Low(KnotVector) to High(KnotVector) do
  begin
    if i <= SplineDegree then KnotVector[i] := 0
    else if i <= (High(KnotVector) - SplineDegree - 1) then KnotVector[i] := (i - SplineDegree) / (Length(FitPoints) - SplineDegree)
    else KnotVector[i] := 1;
  end;
end;

function TSample.GetBasis(Parameter: double): boolean;
var
  m, d, k: integer;
  FirstTerm, SecondTerm: double;
begin
  //http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-coef.html
  Result := False;
  //initialize to 0
  SetLength(Temp, Length(FitPoints));
  For m := Low(Temp) to High(Temp) do Temp[m] := 0.0;
  //special cases
  If Abs(Parameter - KnotVector[0]) < 1e-8 then
  begin
    Temp[0] := 1;
  end
  else if Abs(Parameter - KnotVector[High(KnotVector)]) < 1e-8 then
  begin
    Temp[High(Temp)] := 1;
  end
  else
  begin
    //find knot span [u_k, u_{k+1})
    for k := Low(KnotVector) to High(KnotVector) do if Abs(KnotVector[k] - Parameter) < 1e-8 then break;
    Temp[k] := 1.0;
    for d := 1 to SplineDegree do
    begin
      Temp[k - d] := (KnotVector[k + 1] - Parameter) * Temp[k - d + 1] / (KnotVector[k + 1] - KnotVector[k - d + 1]);
      for m := k - d + 1 to k - 1 do
      begin
        FirstTerm := (Parameter - KnotVector[m]) / (KnotVector[m + d] - KnotVector[m]);
        SecondTerm := (KnotVector[m + d + 1] - Parameter) / (KnotVector[m + d + 1] - KnotVector[m + 1]);
        Temp[m] := FirstTerm * Temp[m] + SecondTerm * Temp[m + 1];
      end;
      Temp[k] := (Parameter - KnotVector[k]) * Temp[k] / (KnotVector[k + d] - KnotVector[k]);
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TSample.FormBasisMatrix;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  SetLength(A, Length(FitPoints), Length(FitPoints));
  for j := Low(A) to High(A) do
  begin
    for i := low(A[j]) to High(A[j]) do //j - row, i - column
    begin
      If GetBasis(KnotVector[j + SplineDegree]) then A[j, i] := Temp[i];
    end;
  end;
end;


var
  i, j, iFitPoints: integer;
  Test: TSample;
  N: array of array of single;
begin
  Test := TSample.Create;
  //define degree
  Test.SplineDegree := 3;
  //random fit points
  iFitPoints := 10;
  SetLength(Test.FitPoints, iFitPoints);
  For i := Low(Test.FitPoints) to High(Test.FitPoints) do
  begin
    Test.FitPoints[i].x := Random()*200;
    Test.FitPoints[i].y := Random()*200;
  end;
  //get knot vector
  Test.GetKnots;
  //get B-Spline basis matrix
  Test.FormBasisMatrix;
  // print matrix
  for j := Low(Test.A) to High(Test.A) do
  begin
    for i := Low(Test.A) to High(Test.A) do write(FloatToStrF(Test.A[j, i], ffFixed, 2, 2) + ', ');
    writeln();
  end;
  readln();
  Test.Free;
end.
```

Comment: Just use debugging. The most probable you have repeated values in KnotVector, but check it yourself.

Comment: @MBo Sure there are repeated values - the first and last 4 (depending on degree) values are the same. Others are not.

Comment: So `(KnotVector[i+p] - KnotVector[i])` is zero for p=1,2,3

Comment: @MBo You are correct. But that's how it is supposed to be. Or let me ask you this: What is the value of basis function N in that case? I'd say it has to be something trivial.

Comment: The algorithm you present does not appear to match that in your link. Is it some sort of attempt at an optimised version of it? The link uses two embedded loops, the outer one of which varies degree from 1 to p. I don't see how your algorithm matches that structure.

Comment: @Dsm it was not my goal to copy that algorithm. My goal is to calcuate the matrix elements - values of basis functions. To do that I simply implemented that recursive formula.

Comment: @Dsm I implemented the algorithm diectly from that page. The divison by zero is now gone, but the result is totally unexpected. (see updated OP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not appear to be the complete answer, but it may help you on your way, and the result is closer to what you expect, but as I say, not completely there.

First of all the knots do not look right to me. The knots appear to form a 'ramp' function (clamped line), and though I can't work out if 'm' has any specific value, I would expect the function to be continuous, which yours is not. Making it continuous gives better results, e.g.

```
procedure TSample.GetKnots();
var
  i, j: integer;
  iL : integer;
begin
  // KNOTS
  //https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-knot-generation.html
  iL := Length( FitPoints );
  SetLength(KnotVector, iL + SplineDegree + 1);
  // set outer knot values and sum used to geterate first internal value
  for i := 0 to SplineDegree - 1 do
  begin
    KnotVector[ i ] := 0;
    KnotVector[ High(KnotVector)-i] := 1;
  end;
  // and internal ones
  for i := 0 to High(KnotVector) - 2* SplineDegree + 1 do
  begin
    KnotVector[ SplineDegree + i - 1] := i / (iL - 1);
  end;
end;
```

I introduced iL = Length( Fitpoints ) for convenience - it is not important.

The second issue I spotted is more of a programming one. In the GetBasis routine, you evaluate k by breaking a for loop. The problem with that is that k is not guaranteed to persist outside the loop, so your use of it later is not guaranteed to succeed (although it may)

Finally, in the same place, your range determination is completely wrong in my opinion. You should be looking for parameter to lie in a half open line segment, but instead you are looking for it to lie close to an endpoint of that line.

Putting these two together

```
   for k := Low(KnotVector) to High(KnotVector) do if Abs(KnotVector[k] - Parameter) < 1e-8 then break;
```

should be replaced by

```
k1 := 0;
for k1 := High(KnotVector) downto Low(KnotVector)  do
begin
  if Parameter >= KnotVector[k1] then
  begin
   k := k1;
   break;
  end;
end;
```

where k1 is an integer.

I can't help feeling that there is a plus 1 error somewhere, but I can't spot it.

Anyway, I hope that this helps you get a bit further.

Comment: Your help is highly appreciated. 

I simply followed [this link](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-knot-generation.html) to generate my knot vector. So according to [this article](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html) the linear system should be solvable. I've choosen my parameter values to equal the lower bound of knot interval / segmnet.

Anyway, using your knot vector definition and replacing my for loop with your block, results in an error. Did you compile it?

Comment: yes, I did compile it and generated the matrix. It was still slightly skewed, but not so much as yours. What was your error? Did you define the extra variables I used? k1 and iL?

Comment: Funny. First line after your code block that evaluates k. So line `Temp[k] := 1.0` raises error due to index `k` being too high (index out of bound).

Comment: I suspect that you are using 'to' rather than 'downto' in the for loop.

Comment: I only copy pasted your block. I can't compile it. `k=10` when the line errors while `Length(Temp) = 10'.

Comment: Anyway, you made a very good point in your answer. You said _"You should be looking for parameter to lie in a half open line segment, but instead you are looking for it to lie close to an endpoint of that line."_ Boy was that sentence important!

Defining `SetLength(Parameter, iL)` with values `i / (iL -1)` and using **second** knot vector definition from [this link](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-knot-generation.html) basically produces desired (and expected result). Doing so, you also have to change the argument of `GetBasis` function in `FormBasisMatrix`.

Comment: As a result to the comment above, I was able to produce expected result. Band Matrix. All the following calculations (not subject to this problem) based on this matrix are correct.
Meaning I'd like to thank you. Maybe edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem, but I don't quite understand your comments, ***SetLength(Parameter, iL)***? I thought *parameter* was a double. And when you say *change the argument of GetBasis*, do you mean *GetKnot* (in order to produce knots based on the reference you give)?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear. I created an array of parameters, that's why the `SetLength`.

Comment: OK, looked at your second knot generation method, but with your choice of parameter values, it is not really any different to the original. It did show a lack of understanding on my part about the value of m in the my original version, and I have corrected that. The knots generated above are identical to the knots generated by the 'second method', so I have not incorporated that part of it.

Answer (score 0):

To build recursive pyramid for coefficient calculation at intervals, you have to start top level of recursion (inner loop of calculations) from the first real (not duplicate) knot index:

```
 For i := Test.Degree...
```

Also check the last loop index.

P.S. You can remove `constructor` and `destructor` from class description and implementation if they have nothing but `inherited`.